# Chef 0.10.4 remote_file resource gets an error when setting backup option to false

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-infra

I am trying to avoid backup of remote_files which i am downloading via chef using following statement:

```
remote_file "#{node[:logneo][:basedir]}/deployedWars/#{war}.war" do
          backup "false"
          source "#{artifactsRepositoryToDeployFrom}/moveit/#{artifactsNameToDeploy}/#{artifactsVersionToDeploy}/wars/#{war}.war"
          owner "iappl"
          group "users"
          mode "0644"
  end
```

I get following error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option backup must be a kind of IntegerFalseClass!  You passed "false".
```

Does anybody knows what can I do to solve this problem? Is my chef version maybe buggy?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending false as a string.  Remove the quotes and that should solve your issue.

```
remote_file "#{node[:logneo][:basedir]}/deployedWars/#{war}.war" do
      backup false
      source "#{artifactsRepositoryToDeployFrom}/moveit/#{artifactsNameToDeploy}/#{artifactsVersionToDeploy}/wars/#{war}.war"
      owner "iappl"
      group "users"
      mode "0644"
end
```

I was able to reproduce your issue and verify my answer now that I had a few minutes.  You have the formatting incorrect in your question for the error message.

The error message is actually:  "Option backup must be a kind of [Integer, FalseClass]".

This means that the backup parameter can be:  false, 0, 1, 2 ,3, etc.